# Can I pass 0 to a function expecting a vector type parameter?

Tags: c++, c++98

I have a function, as such:

```
void foo(int checkInt, vector<int> vect, int x) {
    EXECx = x;
    EXECcheckInt = checkInt;
    if (EXECcheckInt > 0) {
         //do something to vect
    } else {
        Timer.rset();
    }
}
```

As can be seen, `vect` is left alone unless `checkInt` is above 0. So, if I want to pass `checkInt` 0, then it seems like I wouldn't have to worry about `vect`.

Therefore it would seem to me that I need some dummy value to go into this function for `vect`, so what value would work, or do I need to pass a dummy vector? My idea was to just pass 0, but I'm guessing that wouldn't work.

I tried to cast it, as in `foo(0,(vector<int>)0,0)`, but I was surprised that when I tried to print out `vect`, it just showed up as empty (no 0 inside it), with the function written as so:

```
void foo(int checkInt, vector<int> vect, int x) {
    for (auto i = vect.begin(); i != vect.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

How should I go about this?

I'm working with C++98.

Comment: Sounds like you need two separate functions

Comment: What is "do something to vect"? Modifying vect?

Comment: @Jabberwocky The function I'm trying to replicate (its in another language) copies the contents of vect to another vector - this is the 'do something to vect'

Comment: `(vector<int>)0` actually resolves to a `static_cast`, which is just a weird way of calling [constructor #2 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), whose parameter is the desired size.

Comment: perhaps if you change your function signature to void foo( int, vecto<int>*, int x) you mays pass NULL as vector parameter.

Comment: @TrybGhost if `vect` is only read from, then your function should be: `void foo(int checkInt, const vector<int> & vect, int x)`. But you can pass just any `vector<int>` as dummy value anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Change the function declaration to accept a reference of the vector to avoid copying memory unnecessarily like so:

```
void foo(int checkInt, vector<int>& vect, int x)
```

If you already have a vector object then you can pass that even if it is not used. If you need to construct a dummy vector then you can call the function like this:

```
vector<int> v;
foo (0, v, x);
```

Comment: This won't even compile. Temporaries cannot bind to mutable references.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You are right, I have overlooked that; edited.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks like the function decides whether the vector is used or not but what you want to do suggests that it is the caller who decides if the vector is used or not. Who is it really? I think you have a design problem, fix that then you dont need to cast a 0 to a vector anymore. (eg make two functions, one taking a vector, the other taking no vector as parameter)

Anyhow, you may want to look at [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) which is only available since C++17, but it might give you some inspiration on how to handle such situation in a clean way. The "dirty" way is to pass a pointer and then check if it is a `nullptr` inside the function.

Your casts does not create a vector filled with `0` but a vector with size `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide an overload that can be called without the vector. You can refactor the common part into a subfunction:

```
void foo(int checkInt, vector<int> vect, int x) {
    if (checkInt > 0) {
         bar(checkInt, x);
         //do something to vect
    } else {
        foo(checkInt, x);
    }
}

void foo(int checkInt, int x) {
    assert(checkInt <= 0);   // maybe unnecessary. depends on what you need
    bar(checkInt, x);
    Timer.rset();
}

void bar(int checkInt, int x) {
    EXECx = x;
    EXECcheckInt = checkInt;
}

// with vect
foo(checkInt, vect, x);

// without vect
foo(0, 0);
```

---

> but I was surprised that when I tried to print out vect, it just showed up as empty (no 0 inside it)

It's unclear why that surprises you. As per documentation, the constructor of vector that accepts an integer creates that many elements into the constructed vector. A vector with 0 elements is empty.

---

Note that you probably should reconsider whether you would want to pass the vector by value. Are you sure that you need a copy?